# Import an existing code source and edit it with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an epic code source and I want to import it to Android Studio, make some changes and rebuild the apk, in the code source I have two folders; one containing the AndroidManifest.xml file, res... and the other folder named sources containing many .java files, how can I do that please?

Answer (score 1):

While sure, you can open any folder in the IDE and it acts as well as any text editor

If you want build functionality rather than just code editing, Android Studio enforces a particular project layout and `sources` is not part of that layout
 https://developer.android.com/studio/projects#ProjectView

Sounds like you could rename sources to `java` and you're close to that structure

You might also want to verify how this old code structure is built. Is there a `build.gradle` file? If so, then Android Studio can just import that and it'll usually figure out the rest

Comment: thanks for the answer, so I have to manually organize my source code as the structure of an Android studio project before importing  it or else there is another way to modify and rebuild an APK

Comment: As far as I know, yes. And you'd have to figure out how to write a few Gradle files if you don't already have any